# How to run code when a dom element is added firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am making a extension that edits a element on a page but its only working if the element is on the page when it loads (with the website im using it will never happen) so i want to get a event if a div with the id of "427" shows up.

code:

```
var card = !!document.getElementById(427);
console.log(card);
if (card = true) {
    var card = document.getElementById(427)
    var cardimg = card.children.item(9)
    cardimg.setAttribute("style", 'background: transparent url("images/cards/Ultimate_Recipe.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;')
};
```

Comment: Try MutationObserver

Comment: Thats not changing anything, nothing is happing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but you should be careful with memory usage:

```js
const onMutation = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById(427)
  if (element) {
    observer.disconnect()
    elementIsReady(element)
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation)

observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true})
```

You could also use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), by querying each x ms:

```js
new Promise(async (resolve) => {
  let element
  while (!(element = document.getElementById(427))) await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200))
  resolve(element)
}).then(elementIsReady)
```